# Like Box doubled persons

Tags: plugins, facebook-likebox

I am experiencing a weird behavior of Like Box Social Plugin.
When I go to     https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
and enter my facebook page:     http://www.facebook.com/LetUgo.cz
it shows doubled persons in the list (i.e. their face photos).
In other words, almost every person who has liked my page is listed twice.
The number of persons (X people like...) is also incorrect.

When I log out of facebook and show the plugin again, it is correct.
So the wrong behaviour happens only when I am logged into facebook.
The same problem happens to the others who like the page.

When I go to this facebook page, everything is correct. So this problem relates to facebook like box social plugin only.

Does anybody have a clue?
Cheers